# Get PixelValue when click on a picturebox

Tags: c#, pixel, picturebox

I'm working on a .NET C# project and would like to get the pixel value when I click a picturebox, how can I achieve that?

The basic idea is that when I click anywhere in the picturebox, I get the pixelvalue of that image point..

Thanks!

Comment: You mean Color at the point you click?

Comment: Well, yes, color and maybe the byte value at that point..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
private void pictureBox2_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Bitmap b = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
    Color color = b.GetPixel(e.X, e.Y);
}
```

Comment: You are forgetting to check the PictureBox.SizeMode property value.

Comment: yes, I don't know what that is.
Now, can .NET render 16 bits images or do I need to convert them to 24 bits bmp? I ahven't found a way to render 16 bits images without converting first to 24bits bmp..

Answer (score 5):

As @Hans pointed out `Bitmap.GetPixel` should work unless you have different `SizeMode` than `PictureBoxSizeMode.Normal or PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize`. To make it work all the time let's access private property of `PictureBox` named `ImageRectangle`.

```
PropertyInfo imageRectangleProperty = typeof(PictureBox).GetProperty("ImageRectangle", BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
    {
        MouseEventArgs me = (MouseEventArgs)e;

        Bitmap original = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image;

        Color? color = null;
        switch (pictureBox1.SizeMode)
        {
            case PictureBoxSizeMode.Normal:
            case PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize:
                {
                    color = original.GetPixel(me.X, me.Y);
                    break;
                }
            case PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage:
            case PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage:
            case PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom:
                {
                    Rectangle rectangle = (Rectangle)imageRectangleProperty.GetValue(pictureBox1, null);
                    if (rectangle.Contains(me.Location))
                    {
                        using (Bitmap copy = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.ClientSize.Width, pictureBox1.ClientSize.Height))
                        {
                            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(copy))
                            {
                                g.DrawImage(pictureBox1.Image, rectangle);

                                color = copy.GetPixel(me.X, me.Y);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
        }

        if (!color.HasValue)
        {
            //User clicked somewhere there is no image
        }
        else
        { 
            //use color.Value
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Unless that picturebox is in the size of a pixel, I don't think you can. Control onclick events doesn't save specific click location. If you are talking about color, not possible in c#

Comment: I'm doing this:
`private void panel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { Image tempimage = (Image)img[0].RenderImage(0); var bmp = new Bitmap(tempimage); System.Drawing.Color myColor = bmp.GetPixel(MousePosition.X, MousePosition.Y); string hascode = myColor.GetHashCode().ToString(); MessageBox.Show(hascode); }`