# Do the same pictureBox matrix(number of pixels) with loaded images inside?

Tags: c#, picturebox

I set the size for picturebox as 300 x 200, is this guaranteed that loaded image inside will has the same pixel matrix?

Comment: The image itself that controls what the pixel size is. The PictureBox merely displays the image, visually resizing if necessary.

Comment: Then how can I get coordinates of image by click?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18210030/get-pixelvalue-when-click-on-a-picturebox

Comment: Yes, if you mean the display area and if you set the SizeMode=Stretch.